# Cannot find downloaded iso of Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04, iso

I have run the download for 16.04 but the file does not appear on the desktop. I am trying to create a USB. The download has been run a few times and I am still unable to find it on the desktop.

Comment: Your browser may have downloaded it to `~/Downloads` instead. Did you check there?

Comment: Files are not typically downloaded to the desktop. The comment by edwinski is correct. If you are as we assume (as you didn't say) running Ubuntu follow and accept the answer by @andrew.46

Comment: I have a feeling OP is not running Ubuntu as their OS...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way to find a 'lost' iso is to run the following from a Terminal window:

```
find $HOME -iname '*.iso'
```

Details of this command:

- `find` is the command to find the file
- `$HOME` tells it to start looking in your home directory (ie: /home/yourusername/)
- `-iname` tells it to ignore case so you can find it whether it's .iso or .ISO.
- `'*.iso'` uses a wildcard to match any permutation of filename that comes before the `.iso` or `.ISO` section.

An example on my own system:

```
andrew@ilium~$ find $HOME -iname '*.iso'
/home/andrew/Slackware/slackware64-current-iso/slackware64-current-install-dvd.iso
/home/andrew/media/youtube/youtube_spiritual/gayatri.iso
andrew@ilium~$
```

So you can see:

1. The name of the iso file
2. The full path to the iso

And this should be enough for you to find *your* lost file...

Comment: Your information and direction helped find the file.